# Find the values of $a$ and $b$ such that the polynomials have two common roots.

Tags: polynomials, proof-verification

Let $$P(x)=x^3+ax^2+11x+6$$

$$Q(x)=x^3+bx^2+14x+8$$

where $a$ and $b$ real.

What I am not sure of is whether there is single pair $(a,b)$ that satisfies the condition, or infinitely many pairs with some restriction on the variables.

What I did was define the polynomial $$H(x)=P(x)-Q(x) $$which is a quadratic. As this quadratic contains both common roots between $P$ and $Q$, then the two roots of $H(x)$ must be the two common roots. So as they must be real, I set the discriminant to be non negative and thus obtained an inequality in terms of $a$ and $b$. This implied to me a family of solutions.

Is this reasoning correct so far?

Comment: It's a good start but you're not done yet. Finding the roots of $H$ results in finding points where $P(x)=Q(x)$. Hence, you know that a common root of these two polynomials will be in the family of solutions you just found. Once you have this family of solution, any pair $(a,b)$ that will be a root of one of the two polynomial will be a root of the other one.

Comment: Why must the roots of $H$ be real? Couldn't you have a pair of complex conjugates in common?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try a different way- The first equation has roots $p,q,r$ and the second equation has $p,q,s$

Now, $pqr=-6$ and $pqs=-8$ and so, $\frac {r}{s} = \frac 34$

$pq+pr+qr=11$ and $pq+qs+ps=14$ and so, $(p+q)(r-s)=-3$

$p+q=\frac {-3}{r-s}$

Now, substituting in the equation $pq+qr+pr=11$

$\frac {-6}{r}+\frac {-3r}{r-s}=11$  where $s=\frac {4r}3$

So, we get $r=-3$ and $s=-4$

From this, $p+q=-3$ and $pq=2$

You know that $a=p+q+r=-6$  and $b=p+q+s=-7$

Values check out as the first equation will have $-1,-2,-3$ and the second equation - $-1,-2,-4$